# Language switcher for a multilingual site

Tags: javascript, i18n

I have written some javascript code for a multilanguage site. The code works great but I feel like I have a lot of duplicate code. I was wondering if someone can explain how I can make this simpler or minimized. I have tried to use a `forEach(function (item, index)` but it does not seem to be working.

This is the original code that works....

```
(function () {
  var lang1 = "/en/"; //default language
  var lang2 = "/fr/"; //second language
  var lang3 = "/es/"; //third language

 var languageSwitcher = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='/languages']").forEach((el) => el.parentNode.classList.add("language-switcher"));
 document.querySelector("[data-folder='/languages']").classList.add("language-switcher");
  
  document.querySelectorAll(".language-switcher .header-nav-folder-item").forEach((el) => el.classList.add("languages"));
 document.querySelectorAll(".language-switcher .header-menu-nav-item:not(:first-child)").forEach((el) => el.classList.add("languages"));
  var languages = document.querySelectorAll(".languages");
  
  var language1 = document.querySelectorAll(".language-switcher .languages a[href*='"+lang1+"']");
  var language2 = document.querySelectorAll(".language-switcher .languages a[href*='"+lang2+"']")
  var language3 = document.querySelectorAll(".language-switcher .languages a[href*='"+lang3+"']")

  var windowURL = window.location.href;
  var pageURL = windowURL.split("/")[4];

  if (pageURL == undefined) {
    for (var i = 0; i < language1.length; i++) {
      language1[i].onclick = function () {
        var path = lang1 + "home";
        this.href = path;
      };
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < language2.length; i++) {
      language2[i].onclick = function () {
        var path = lang2 + "home";
        this.href = path;
      };
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < language3.length; i++) {
      language3[i].onclick = function () {
        var path = lang3 + "home";
        this.href = path;
      };
    }
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < language1.length; i++) {
      language1[i].onclick = function () {
        var path = lang1 + pageURL;
        this.href = path;
      };
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < language2.length; i++) {
      language2[i].onclick = function () {
        var path = lang2 + pageURL;
        this.href = path;
      };
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < language3.length; i++) {
      language3[i].onclick = function () {
        var path = lang3 + pageURL;
        this.href = path;
      };
    }
  }

 document.querySelectorAll(".header-nav-item:not(.language-switcher) a").forEach((el) => el.classList.add("language"));
  document.querySelectorAll(".header-menu-nav-item:not(.language-switcher) a").forEach((el) => el.classList.add("language"));
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-folder="/languages"] .header-menu-nav-item a').forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("language"));

  var languageLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".language");

  for (var i = 0; i < languageLinks.length; i++) {
    var navURL = languageLinks[i].href;
    if (windowURL.indexOf(lang1) != -1) {
      languages.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("active"));
      languages[0].classList.add("active");
      if (navURL.indexOf(lang1) != -1) {
        languageLinks[i].closest("div").style.display = "block";
      } else {
        languageLinks[i].closest("div").style.display = "none";
      }
    } else if (windowURL.indexOf(lang2) != -1) {
      languages.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("active"));
      languages[1].classList.add("active");
      if (navURL.indexOf(lang2) != -1) {
        languageLinks[i].closest("div").style.display = "block";
      } else {
        languageLinks[i].closest("div").style.display = "none";
      }
    } else if (windowURL.indexOf(lang3) != -1) {
      if (navURL.indexOf(lang3) != -1) {
        languages.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("active"));
        languages[2].classList.add("active");
        languageLinks[i].closest("div").style.display = "block";
      } else {
        languageLinks[i].closest("div").style.display = "none";
      }
    } else {
      if (navURL.indexOf(lang1) != -1) {
        languages.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("active"));
        languages[0].classList.add("active");
        languageLinks[i].closest("div").style.display = "block";
      } else {
        languageLinks[i].closest("div").style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }

  var active = document.querySelector(".language-switcher .active");
  active.closest(".language-switcher").prepend(active);
  document.querySelectorAll(".header a").forEach((el) => (el.style.visibility = "visible"));
  languageSwitcher.style.display = "flex";
})();
```

I have attempted to use a forEach function and an array but it is not working.

> ```
>  (function () {
>   var lang = ["/en/", "/fr/", "/es/"];
>   
>   document
>     .querySelectorAll("a[href='/languages']")
>     .forEach((el) => el.parentNode.classList.add("language-switcher"));
>
>   document
>     .querySelector("[data-folder='/languages']")
>     .classList.add("language-switcher");
>
>   document
>     .querySelectorAll(".language-switcher .header-nav-folder-item")
>
>     .forEach((el) => el.classList.add("languages"));
>   document
>     .querySelectorAll(
>       ".language-switcher .header-menu-nav-item:not(:first-child)"
>     )
>     .forEach((el) => el.classList.add("languages"));
>
>   var languages = document.querySelectorAll(".languages"); //langauge switcher language options
>
>
>   document
>     .querySelectorAll(".header-nav-item:not(.language-switcher) a")
>
>     .forEach((el) => el.classList.add("language"));
>   document
>     .querySelectorAll(".header-menu-nav-item:not(.language-switcher) a")
>
>     .forEach((el) => el.classList.add("language"));
>   document
>     .querySelectorAll('[data-folder="/languages"] .header-menu-nav-item a')
>
>     .forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("language"));
>
>   var languageLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".language"); // languages set in navigation links
>
>
>   var windowURL = window.location.href;
>   var pageURL = windowURL.split("/")[4];
>
>   var language = document.querySelectorAll(".language-switcher .languages a");
>
>   for (var i = 0; i < language.length; i++) {
>     lang.forEach(function (item, index) {
>       if (pageURL == undefined) {
>         language[index].onclick = function () {
>           var path = item + "home";
>           this.href = path;
>         };
>       } else {
>         language[index].onclick = function () {
>           var path = item + pageURL;
>           this.href = path;
>         };
>       }
>     });
>   }
>
>   for (var j = 0; j < languageLinks.length; j++) {
>     var navURL = languageLinks[j].href;
>     for (var k = 0; k < lang.length; k++) {
>     if (windowURL.indexOf(lang[k]) != -1) {
>       languages.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("active"));
>       languages[k].classList.add("active");
>       if (navURL.indexOf(lang[k]) != -1) {
>         languageLinks[j].closest("div").style.display = "block";
>       } else {
>         languageLinks[j].closest("div").style.display = "none";
>       }
>     } else {
>       if (navURL.indexOf(lang[0]) != -1) {
>         languages.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("active"));
>         languages[0].classList.add("active");
>         languageLinks[j].closest("div").style.display = "block";
>       } else {
>         languageLinks[j].closest("div").style.display = "none";
>       }
>     }
>   }
>   }
>
>   document.querySelector(".header").style.visibility = "visible";
>   var active = document.querySelector(".language-switcher .active");
>
>   active.closest(".language-switcher").prepend(active);
> })();
> ```

Comment: What does your code attempt to do (tasks)?

Comment: It is for having multiple languages on a website. Each page has a prefix added to the url. For example all the English pages would be domainname.com/en/pagename. The code then matches the windowurl to the pagelinks and hides the pages that don't have that prefix.

It works well but I have a lot of if language1 do this.... if language2 do this... etc. I am wondering if there is a way to simplify that so that I don't have to have an if else for each language.

Comment: Hmm... (I don't know much of javascript but,) do you need other than find the "windowurl" language pointing string ("/en/", "/fr/", "/es/", ... ) and then insert it to the query string to pick pages ... (if your English pages are under "domain.com/en/", French pages under "domain.com/fr/", etc.)?